# How can I get the video's image in JW Player?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

How can I get the video's image to using with `sendEvent();` in JW Player? For example i'm using

```
var playerx = document.getElementById(player);
playerx.sendEvent("LOAD","http://www.domain.com/videos/"+x);
playerx.sendEvent("PLAY","true");
```

for click event for starting the videos while clicking a video's thumb in a page. I want x's thumb comes with player's flashvars in.

```
file=x.flv&image=videos/thumbs/xxx.png
```

I want to get the thumb when on click in this embed code's flashvars.

---

**I found the solution;**

```
player.sendEvent("LOAD",{'file': 'http://www.domain.com/videos/x.flv', 'image':'videos/thumbs/thumb.jpg'});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you wondering how to send in a video with a new thumbnail, or how to get the URL of the thumbnail once it's been loaded into the player?

Answer (score 0):

with JW Player >=5.2

```
jwplayer().load({
    file:'http://mydomain.com/my.mov',
    image:'http://mydomain.com/myposter.jpg'
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
playlist: [{
    file: "http://file url",
    image: "https://image URL",
    title: "title"
```

Comment: Try adding some text to your answer too instead of a small snippet of code.